# How do you pass a file or folder containing whitespace as an argument to a command-line program in a GNU/Linux or Cygwin environment?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, cygwin

There are occasions when you are working with files and folders that contain spaces in them. The problem is any time you try and pipe  files / folders containing whitespace to another command-line program, the files / folders containing whitespace are interpreted as separate arguments rather than as a single argument. For example, consider the following directory tree:

```
Folder With Spaces
Folder With Spaces/FolderWithoutSpaces
Folder With Spaces/FolderWithoutSpaces/file with spaces.txt
FolderWithoutSpaces
FolderWithoutSpaces/fileWithoutSpaces.txt
```

If you try and run a shell command such as "grep 'some text' $(find . -type f)", you'll get the following output:

```
grep: ./Folder: No such file or directory
grep: With: No such file or directory
grep: Spaces/FolderWithoutSpaces/file: No such file or directory
grep: with: No such file or directory
grep: spaces.txt: No such file or directory
```

The big question is, how do you pipe files / folders that have whitespace in them as arguments to a command line program?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would be better off using the `-exec` action (option) of `find`
and quoting your arguments.

Example:

```
find . -type f -exec grep stuff '{}' \;
```

The quotes will keep the spaces from being interpreted and you don't have to pipe everything through `xargs` unnecessarily.

From the `find` man page:

> `-exec` *command* **`;`**
>
>   Execute
>   *command*
>   ; true if 0 status is returned.  All following arguments to
>   `find`
>   are taken to be arguments to the command
>     until  an  argument consisting  of  ‘
>   **`;`**
>   ’  is encountered. 
>     The string  ‘
>   `{}`
>   ’  is replaced by the current file name being processed everywhere it occurs
>     in the arguments to the command, not just in arguments where it is alone, as in some versions of
>   `find`
>   .  Both of these constructions might
>     need  to  be escaped  (with  a  ‘
>   `\`
>   ’) or quoted to protect them from expansion by the shell.  See the
>   **EXAMPLES**
>   section for examples of the
>     use of the
>   `-exec`
>   option.  The specified command is run once for each matched file.  The command is executed in the starting directory.
>
> There  are  unavoidable security problems surrounding use of the `-exec` action; you should use the `-execdir` option instead.

Comment: I use -exec on a routine basis, but for some reason it never occurred to me to simply put quotation marks around the brackets!

Comment: Actually, putting the `{}` in quotes has nothing to do with handling names that have spaces in them.

Answer (score 4):

Pipe in your arguments using xargs by delimiting your command line arguments in the preceding program with a null character passing the "-0" option to xargs, such as follows:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l "some text"
```

This command will pass in any files / folders with whitespaces in them as single arguments rather than separate arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Use the backslash character '\' preceeding the whitespace:

```
[randerson@localhost ~]$ mkdir Folder\ With\ Spaces
[randerson@localhost ~]$ ls | grep Folder\ With\ Spaces
Folder With Spaces
[randerson@localhost ~]$
```

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the file names in (single or double) quotation marks:

```
$ mkdir "Folder With Spaces"
$ ls | grep "Folder With Spaces"
Folder With Spaces
$ ls | grep 'Folder With Spaces'
Folder With Spaces
```

The shell will expand variables inside double quotation marks:

```
$ FOO=With
$ ls | grep "Folder $FOO Spaces"
Folder With Spaces
```

You can also quote `$(...)` expansions if the result is a single filename:

```
$ ls -d "$(echo -n Folder With Spaces)"
Folder With Spaces
```

This will only work for single file names; for multiple files, use `find -exec` or `xargs` as suggested in the other answers.